# How can I reshape my data and make a bar graph from it using R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

For my Dissertation I was given a large dataset concerning a study that involved looking at the Microbiome of patients with Parkinsons in comparison to controls. In the data set there are approx 200 controls and 200 Parkinsons patients (PD) and I was interested in finding out which drug is the most common among Parkinsons patients. I have attached a screenshot the R file containing the filtered-out data that I am interested in and as you can see the Drugs listed (there are 19 total) all have observations of Y(yes) or N(No) and I am only trying to count the Y responses for each drug in PD patients and compare it to controls.
[Controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adlDE.png)[Parkinsons patients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEemx.png). I wanted to reshape the data and create a new table like this:
[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBmvm.png) containing all the Y (yes) observations for every drug in the dataset (19) and for controls in comparison to PD patients. From this I wanted to create a bar graph like this:
[example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjjtk.png) with the name of the drugs on the X axis and the Frequency of Yes responses on the Y axis with 2 bars-Control and PD patients.

```
data2 <- Source_Data_24Oct2022 %>%
  select(, 37:55) %>%
  View()

data3 <- Source_Data_24Oct2022 %>%
  filter(Case_status %in% c("PD", "Control")) %>%
  select(Case_status, Antibiotics_current, Antibiotics_past_3_months, Laxatives, Indigestion_drugs, Anti_inflammatory_drugs, Radiation_Chemo, Blood_thinners, Cholesterol_med, Blood_pressure_med, Thyroid_med, Asthma_or_COPD_med, Diabetes_med, Pain_med, Depression_anxiety_mood_med, Birth_control_or_estrogen, Antihistamines, Probiotic, Co_Q_10, Sleep_aid) %>%
  View()

data4 <- data3 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = 2:20, names_to = "Drug", values_to = "Response") %>%
  filter(Response == "Y") %>%
  group_by(Case_status) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  View()
```

That is some of the code I tried to use, as you can see I have no idea what I'm doing and any help/recommendations or examples of how you would code for this would be very appreciated. My colleague made the example graph above by doing:

```
tidy_data <- Book3 %>%
  filter(Case_status %in% c("PD", "Control")) %>%
  select(starts_with("Day_of_stool_collection_"), Case_status, Constipation, Diarrhea, Intestinal_disease) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Case_status, names_to = "Symptom", values_to = "Response") %>%
  filter(Response == "Y") %>%
  group_by(Case_status, Symptom) %>%
  summarise(Count = n())

ggplot(tidy_data, aes(x = Symptom, y = Count, fill = Case_status)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  labs(
    title = "Frequency of 'Yes' Responses for Symptoms in PD and Control Groups",
    x = "Symptoms", y = "Frequency of 'Yes' Responses"
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

I tried to follow this using my variables but it has not worked.

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of `dput(Source_Data_24Oct2022)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(Source_Data_24Oct2022, 20))`.

Answer (score 1):

I have edited the code your peer provided to look something like this:

```
drug_table <- data.frame(values = c(13, 78, 45, 78, 65, 46, 34, 56, 12, 90, 18, 89, 33, 67), 
               drugs = rep(c("Antibiotics_Current",
                             "Antibiotics_past_3_months",
                             "Laxatives", "Blood_thinners",
                             "Diabetes_med", "Thyroid_med",
                             "Anti_inflammatory_drugs"),
                           each = 2),
               disease = c("PD", "Control"))




ggplot(drug_table, aes(x = drugs, y = values, fill = disease)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  labs(
    title = "Drug use among PD patients",
    x = "Drug", y = "Count") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

This produces a graph that looks similar to what you are aiming for:
[image]

More details on how to change aesthetics using ggplot2 can be found here: https://rstudio.github.io/cheatsheets/html/data-visualization.html